# How to dynamically create variables from .csv files in a folder?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, variables, dynamic

I have a folder with any number of .csv files. For all intents and purposes let's say I have three now: map1.csv, map2.csv and map3.csv.

I want to import the contents of these .csv files into a dataframe with a name that is the same as the filename they came from. So the content of map1.csv in folder ### needs to be in a dataframe named map1 (or map1.csv).

I know creating variables dynamically is not the best thing, but it is what I need exactly. So if there are better ways to tackle my problem I'd be happy to learn.

Thanks in advance :)

Here's what I tried:
filenames obviously contains the names of the files
csv_files contains the paths to those files
count is number of files in the folder
path is the path of the folder which contains the files

```
import pandas as pd
from tkinter.filedialog import askdirectory
import fnmatch 
import os
import glob

path = askdirectory(title='Select Folder') # shows dialog box and return the path
count = int(len(fnmatch.filter(os.listdir(path), '*.*')))
filenames = os.listdir(path)
csv_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(path, "*.csv"))

for i in range(count):
    var_name = filenames[i]
    value = pd.read_csv(csv_files[i])
    globals()[var_name]= value

print(Map1.csv)
```

Comment: How about using a dictionary, where the keys are filenames and the values are your dataframes? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-variable-variables. (By the way, `map1.csv` is an invalid variable name because of the period, but it is a valid dictionary key.)

Comment: I've have seen more posts indeed about dictionaries, however I am unfamiliar with dictionaries sadly. In your example given, would it be possible to loop through an n number of files using a dict like I need? And if so, what would that look like in python.

Answer (score 1):

A Python dictionary is the appropriate data structure here: the keys would be your filenames and the values the dataframes you create.

The code could also be improved by removing `count` and `filenames` (which include any non-CSV files that might be present) and just working with `csv_files`.

For example, starting from the point where you already have `csv_files`:

```
df_dict = {}  # Create an empty dictionary

for csv_f in csv_files:
    fname = os.path.basename(csv_f)  # Just the filename without directory prefix
    df = pd.read_csv(csv_f)
    df_dict[fname] = df  # Add a dictionary entry where the key is <fname> and the value is <df>

print(df_dict['Map1.csv'])  # Get the value corresponding to a particular dictionary key
```

It's definitely worth reading more and getting familiar with dictionaries, since they're a fundamental data structure in Python. You could look at: https://realpython.com/python-dicts/